# Why doesn't this Less compile? What can I do to fix it?

Tags: css, less

As this is, it complains that:

> SyntaxError: error evaluating function `darken`: a.toHSL is not a function on line 24, column 1:

It seems like this should work; what am I doing wrong? How can I get the effect that I want?

```
@red2: #842211;
@green2: #842212;
@blue2: #842213;

@colors: red2, blue2, green2;

.color-style-helpers(@colors; @index) when (@index > 0) {
  .color-style-helpers(@colors; (@index - 1));

  @colorName : extract(@colors, @index);
  @color : ~"@{@{colorName}}";
  // @color : #ffffff; // Uncomment this line and this will work
  @darkColor : darken(@color, 10%);      

  .background-@{colorName} {    
    border-color: @darkColor;
    background-color: @color;
  }     
}


.color-style-helpers(@colors; length(@colors););
```

You can see the results [here](http://lesscss.org/less-preview/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22%40red2%3A%20%23842211%3B%5Cn%40green2%3A%20%23842212%3B%5Cn%40blue2%3A%20%23842213%3B%5Cn%5Cn%40colors%3A%20red2%2C%20blue2%2C%20green2%3B%5Cn%5Cn.color-style-helpers(%40colors%3B%20%40index)%20when%20(%40index%20%3E%200)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20.color-style-helpers(%40colors%3B%20(%40index%20-%201))%3B%5Cn%20%5Cn%20%20%40colorName%20%3A%20extract(%40colors%2C%20%40index)%3B%5Cn%20%20%40color%20%3A%20~%5C%22%40%7B%40%7BcolorName%7D%7D%5C%22%3B%5Cn%2F%2F%20%20%40color%20%3A%20%23ffffff%3B%20%2F%2F%20removing%20this%20line%20causes%20an%20error%5Cn%20%20%40darkColor%20%3A%20darken(%40color%2C%2010%25)%3B%5Cn%20%20%5Cn%20%5Cn%20%20.background-%40%7BcolorName%7D%20%7B%20%20%20%20%5Cn%20%20%20%20border-color%3A%20%40darkColor%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20background-color%3A%20%40color%3B%5Cn%20%20%7D%5Cn%20%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn%5Ct%5Cn.color-style-helpers(%40colors%3B%20length(%40colors)%3B)%3B%22%7D)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the below line of code in your example. It makes the content of the `@color` var be treated as a string instead of a color. Because of this, the Less compiler couldn't convert the color to its HSL value which is required for the `darken` function and thus results in the error.

```
@color : ~"@{@{colorName}}";
```

Instead of that, just use the double `@` syntax. There is no need for the wrapping quotes or the escape function for your case.

```
@color : @@colorName;
```

Comment: Could have sworn I tried that before...Guess not. Thanks :)